# Задваивается вывод (Django)

Tags: python, html5, jinja2

Всем привет! Пытаюсь сделать вывод по категориям без перехода на отдельную страницу. Всё работает хорошо, кроме первой загрузки сайта, когда, как я понимаю условие на проверку категорий некорректно работает и оба цикла работают. ператор 'with' не даёт ничего. Как исправить?

Код файла:

```
<div class="portfolioFilter">
            <ul class="Portfolio-nav wow fadeIn delay-02s">
                <li><a href="#" data-filter=" .all" class="current">Все категории</a></li>
                {% for c in cats %}
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter=" .{{ c.name }} ">{{ c.name }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="portfolioContainer wow fadeInUp delay-04s">
        {% for post in pr %}
            {% for c in cats %}
                {% if post.availability %}
                    {% if post.group.name == c.name %}
                        <div class=" Portfolio-box {{ c.name }}">
                            <a href="img/Portfolio-pic3.jpg"><img src="{{ post.img.url }}" alt=""></a>
                            <h3>{{ post.name }}</h3>
                            <p>{{ post.description }}</p>
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        <div class=" Portfolio-box all">
                            <a href="img/Portfolio-pic3.jpg"><img src="{{ post.img.url }}" alt=""></a>
                            <h3>{{ post.name }}</h3>
                            <p>{{ post.description }}</p>
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Первая загрузка страницы(неверное отображение)
[image: Первая загрузка страницы]

Выбранная категория(верное отображение)
[image: Прогрузка категории]

Возврат ко всем продуктам(верное отображение)
[image: Возврат ко всем продуктам]

Код View
[image: View]

Comment: Здравствуйте! Невозможно увидеть полную картину без кода самого view. Не могли бы вы его прикрепить? Возможно, обработку будет проще делать в самом view а не в html-файле

Comment: @biflé Прикрепил!

Comment: Уберите `{% for c in cats %}` внутри  цикла по posts

Comment: @Александр не помогло, но проблему решил!